# Как собрать из отмеченных чекбоксов массив объектов в той же иерархии?

Tags: javascript

У меня [**тут**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngzpgu?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.ts) уже есть набросок, но там идет построение в стиле

```
[ 
  { 
    "name": "Folder 1", 
    "content": ["file1"]
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "Folder 2", 
    "content": ["file2"] 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "Folder 2", 
    "content": ["file3"] 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "Folder 2", 
    "content": ["file4"]
  } 
]
```

Т.е. при каждом клике на чекбокс, метод push кидает их в один массив подряд. А мне нужно чтобы они группировались на категории, имеется ввиду как в исходном массиве **mainArr** [тут](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngzpgu?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.ts)

```
[ 
 { 
  "name": "Folder 1", 
  "content": ["file1"]
 }, 
 { 
  "name": "Folder 2", 
  "content": [ 
    "file2",
    "file3",
    "file4"
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: `this.output[name].push({ value });`?

Comment: Перед добавлением, искать `arr.find(e => e.name == obj.name)` где arr — большой массив, obj - добавляемый объект. Если найдется, добавить контент туда, иначе push-ить в массив. Можно также параллельно собрать другую структуру, где ключами будут названия `name`. Минус память, плюс скорость.